# Function keys on an external keyboard

Tags: keyboard, volume-control, function-keys

So I bought a keyboard for my laptop. Unfortunately, it doesn't have the function key (though I know many people say it's useless). On my laptop, I control volume with the function key and F9-11. How can I get the same functionality on my external keyboard? The advanced keyboard settings don't have an option related to the function key.

More specifically, it would be great if I could map it to my 'Menu' key which I'm never going to use.

Or is there a way to get full functionality without it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you open the keyboard settings, then click the 'shortcuts' tab, then select the "sound & media" page, you can change the shorcut for mute, up and down.  I tested <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Menu</kbd> for mute, <kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>Menu</kbd> for down, and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Menu</kbd> for up and it seems to work OK.

Weird way of doing it though - the modifier key denotes the function while you just hit the menu key for action.

Comment: Thanks. Small difference though, my fault - I use Kubuntu. So I had to go to Shortcuts -> KMix. Also, when I tried to set it to Super-Menu (or anything with Menu), it popped up the menu instead of registering it as part of the shortcut. I couldn't find an option to disable it either. I'm currently using Super, and that's just as good. Better, actually. Thanks!